# Android File Browser throws IO Exception?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, browser

The following code throws an IO Exception. Any Ideas? This code is for a file browser as part of a music making application and I'd like to show the user what audio loops they have in a folder(assets).

```
package com.razor5cl.droiddub;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BrowserActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String button = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] fileNames =assetManager.list("loops");

    }
}
```

[EDIT] Sorry for the delay guys. Here is the promised XML code as well:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#111111"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="467dp" />

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#111111"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >   
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="@string/preview_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/preview_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="@string/select_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/select_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And a stack trace:

```
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): FATAL EXCEPTION: 02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.razor5cl.droiddub/com.razor5cl.droiddub.BrowserActivity}:    java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at com.razor5cl.droiddub.BrowserActivity.onCreate(BrowserActivity.java:21)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-24 10:04:42.445: E/AndroidRuntime(10029):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please give us the full stack trace for crashes.

Comment: It says I'm getting an unhandled IOException, and when i Try-Catch it, the app crashes and I get the following in LogCat:

Comment: 02-15 21:51:20.558: E/AndroidRuntime(23389): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Its really hard to help without stacktrace, may be you haven't set permissions, may be the folder doesnt exists....

Answer (score 0):

you ned to set the list view

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames );
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

for an example please have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: This still didn't work, I get runtime exception due to not having a listview with the id list, even though I do.

Comment: your layout activity_browser must have an list view with an id. your specify the id and set the list. please add the full stacktrace and the xml of the activity_browser

Comment: I will add the necessary XML when I get to my PC later on.

Comment: ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileNames );
setListAdapter(adapter);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I have it working now, but I'm having trouble finding the assets folder. If i put the path as     assets, I just get a blank list.

Comment: so, please close this question and open a new.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exception from comments-  you're implementing a ListActivity, but there's no ListView in your layout.  Either add a list with id android:id.list, or derive from Activity instead of ListActivity.

Comment: I have a listview that has the id list, though.